# how to reference another attribute mongoid selection :created_at.gte => :some_other_timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

With Mongoid on a Rails 3 app

I want to run a comparison query as such

Model.where(:created_at.gte => (:some_other_timestamp))

Answer (score 1):

Try using a JavaScript expression inside the query ([`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)), like this one:

```
Model.where('this.created_at >= this.some_other_timestamp')
```

Comment: Is this time efficient across 11 million documents?